# Finding lapse rate (value for dT/dh)

Tags: matlab

I have a temperature dataset with surface temperatures and a second dataset with the corresponding elevation at which these temperatures are measured. How can I find the aprroximate lapse rate between those 2 datasets? I can use MatLab but I don't know what to do.

So dT/dh = ...?

Thanks!

Comment: diff(T)./diff(h) maybe?

Comment: use diff function! it's the best and fastest solution